# WSO2 EMM - operation not working

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I want to test device management operation on my registered device, I set notifier type to be both local and GCM, but nothing happen on device.
also I change notifier type to be just local and check operation again, nothing this time.
Also application list, device battery, ram and location not shown in [this](http://tinypic.com/r/4pxicj/8) page
How can I fix these issues.

More info:
server : windows 7 (wso2 v : 1.1.0),
client : galaxy note 10.1 (android),
database : mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since notification method is being pushed to the device at the time of enrolment, when you change the notification type (to GCM or Local), you should have to re-enroll the ​device to the system.
Have you tried that as well?

​Other thing is do you use ADB (Android Debug Bridge) to debug the Android device? If so, please check the debugging messages of the android agent to check whether if there are any issues being logged there.

Comment: I unregistered the device and set the notifier type to local and registered again. I test some of the operation and now they work. Can I change the notifier typ without unregistering the device?

Comment: No you cant do that. As I mentioned earlier, notification method is pushed to the device at the time of enrolment.